# how do I get date field in certain string format

Tags: select, date-format

my table has below columns

A:  date
B: date
C:
 and many more columns,

I do not want use to_char(A, date_format),  how I can do
select * from mytable,  and the returned A, B column are in certain date_format

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You on Oracle? On my profile here there are a few articles on how to ask questions here - you might want to take a look? The more information you can give us, the more we can help! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Check your SQL client and see if you can configure it to format dates in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what RDBMS you're using, but since you've referenced TO_CHAR I will assume Oracle. You can set the session property NLS_DATE_FORMAT to control to default date format used. See [this link](http://dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format_sysdate.htm) for info.